# Как поставить bitrix + virtualbox + windows10 64bit?

Tags: битрикс, virtualbox, windows-10

Доброе утро.
Ребята, подскажите, пож-та, как решить такую проблему:

- Задача: запустить образ 1c-bitrix на виртуальной машине (windows 10
  64bit).
- Мои действия: скачиваю образ 1c-bitrix с официального сайта, оставляю
  стандартные настройки, запускаю образ.
- Проблема: при загрузке СentOS возникает ошибка: This kernel requires
  an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.(скриншот в аттаче). Я
  так понимаю, что где-то в настройках VirtualBox нужно просто
  правильный CPU определить, но, покопавшись, не нашёл нужной
  настройки.

Заранее спасибо[image: ![Скрин]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS10W.jpg)

Comment: Процессор какой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что в БИОС включена аппаратная виртуализация.

Comment: Спасибо!
Проблема была в отключенной виртуализации в БИОС.